# How to transform/Encoding for list of values(integers or float)

Tags: python, scipy, feature-extraction, word2vec

I am trying to encode a dataframe like below:

A B C
2 'Hello' [1, 0, .5]
1 'All'   [.8, .3, 1]

I am not able to figure out how to go about passing the third column values directly to my array without transforming which is having list of integer/float values(I got third column from word2vec. 
I want to pass the same values without transforming

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what you want as result?

Comment: I want a transformed matrix , i am using LabelEncoder for strings, MultiLabelBinarizer for list of string but i am not sure how to encode list of integers. I want to  pass these integer /float values as it is to my transfor med matrix X. Currently when i try to pass the list of inetegers i get 'setting an array element with sequence' error. Notsure how to go about this. Plz suggest if there is any specific transformer or any technique i can use to do this. i want transformed numpy array as result

Comment: What does the integers in list represent? I mean why the first list have 3 items [1,0,.5] and second have [.8, .3]?

Comment: I got third column after  Word2Vec which i need to concatenate/append/transform into final array(X) , I am not sure whether we get exactly same length list or different after Word2Vec/WordVector . I am kind of newbie.

Comment: Then you should add a word2vec tag in the question and also post some code how you got the data, so others can help